# Clearly expression in electric field strength

Tags: electrostatics

For a uniformly charged disk the field strength in z axis(z axis passes through the center of disk) is equal to $ε(z)=(\frac{2KQ}{a^2}) (1-\frac{z}{\sqrt{a^2+z^2}})$

In case $z\gg a$,
$ε(z)= \frac{2KQ}{a^2}(1-(1-\frac{a^2}{2 z^2}))$

I cant understand why $(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{a^2}{z^2}}})=(1-\frac{a^2}{2 z^2})$

a is radius of disk, K is
dielectric constant

Comment: Hey, so some clarifications: what is a, the radius of the disk? What is K? And you don't need to do* for multiplication normally youth can leave those out or use \cdot $\cdot$ that also helps

Comment: thanks for your warnings, i thing that is better

Comment: There are still some things wrong, i would fix it but on a phone that is too much fiddling for me^^. as a rule avoid fractions in exponents that is just a pain to format, and per expression just one set of dollar signs is enough and you can really leave the multiplication signs out unless it is very ambiguous otherwise. :) hope that helps

Comment: Finally I think they used $\sqrt{1+x}\approx 1+x/2$ which holds for small x (I think... if you correct the formatting of the question it will be easier to see ;) )

Comment: But it has -1/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: a Taylor expansion of the function $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}}$ around $x=0$ can be used, if you realize $z>>a$ makes this viable...

(Also there are still brackets missing etc. In your question... and I fixed my own latex now....)

Comment: From Taylor Series is equal to 1-x+x^2-x^3.... So he use 1-x/2, maybe  he divide by 2 to simplify the result?

Comment: No you missed a part of the derivative don't forget the exponent , also going to order 1 is enough

Comment: correct! thanks